# rvm /usr/bin/env: ruby no such file error

Tags: environment-variables, ruby, rvm

I've installed rvm + ruby systemwide.

```
which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
```

and:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

Everything else works fine, putting direct path of ruby in my executables work fine.

Comment: Have you added "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin" to the "PATH" in "/etc/login.defs"?

Answer (score 9):

The PATH is what the `env` program uses to search for your executables. You can change this per-user (in the $HOME/.bashrc). In order to do that, run `nano $HOME/.bashrc` and go to the last line, add a new line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin
```

To change it at a system level you `sudo nano /etc/login.defs` and change this line

```
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

to

```
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin
```

Comment: I'm actually receiving the same error. ENV_PATH didn't help. I've added it to both ENV_PATH for normal user and super user. Is login the correct file for headless bash?

Comment: @SandroDzneladze: In Ubuntu the PATH variable is set in `/etc/environment`. That's where I would change it rather than in `/etc/login.defs`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson looks like a better place yes. But it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I tried the solution, somehow it is not working for ruby-2.2.2 and Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a somewhat old question, but I spent a day+ trying to nail this problem down, and I found what I think is a solid best practices type of solution -- use the `rvm` wrappers.

`/usr/bin/env ruby` gives you the capability to use the Ruby version of your choice so you don't have to edit the executable shell scripts (in `/bin`) with a hard coded directory path to make them work (I've seen this as a suggested fix elsewhere).

As noted in the answers above, the key is the `$PATH` setting in `/etc/environment`, but I came up with a different solution.

RVM gives us a symbolic link directory of all the installed ruby versions and aliases at `/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/`.

If you set your `$PATH` var to use the wrapper directory associated with the Ruby version you want to use e.g.

```
PATH="/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p547:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

You will have set the RVM environment such that `/usr/bin/env ruby_command` will work.

At least this resolved this problem for me. I hope this helps someone out there save some time.

Comment: I tried the solution, somehow it is not working for ruby-2.2.2 and Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: What's the error? There are some install issues on Ubuntu with Ruby 2.2.+: http://ryanbigg.com/2014/10/ubuntu-ruby-ruby-install-chruby-and-you/  I'm still using v1.9.3 -- not looking forward to upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced this issue and took a different approach, so thought of sharing it. This happens when the ruby file is not present in the directory mentioned. So create a symbolic link to the ruby file in the directory and your error should be fixed.

cd /usr/bin/env

ln -s /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby

Comment: Hello Nihanth and than you for the answer!  /usr/bin/env is not a directory on Ubuntu machines.  Also your link command is missing a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error

`#!/usr/bin/env ruby`  in top of my script leads to

```
rvm /usr/bin/env: ruby no such file error
```

if I execute the script.

My solution was as simple as hard to find:

The encoding of linefeeds in my script /sourcecode editor was set to "windows style (CR + LF)".

After switching it to "unix style (LF)" and saving my script again, the error is gone.

Seems the Carriage return (CR) sign was left behind the "ruby" so theres no `ruby filname.script` but `ruby\R filename.script` which leads to the error.